# ¿Porqué no me pone los datos SQL en PHP?

Tags: php, sql

Buenas, estoy intentando hacer una conexión a una base de Datos SQL con Phpmyadmin y cuándo es a la hora de mostrar los datos de las tablas me lo muestra sin problemas, sin embargo, cuándo quiero hacer entradas no me deja y me da el error `or die()` que había programado.
Agradecería ayuda, me está matando.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>DB</title>
 
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
 <label>Nombre:</label>
 <input type="text" name="nombre">
 <br>
 <label>Apellido:</label>
 <input type="text" name="apellido">
 <br>
 <label>Correo:</label>
 <input type="email" name="correo">
 <br>
 <label>Contraseña:</label>
 <input type="password" name="contrasena">
 <br>
 <br>
 <input type="submit" name="registrar">
</form>
<?php 

include 'conexion.php';

if (isset($_POST['registrar'])) {
 $nombre1=$_POST['nombre'];
 $apellido1=$_POST['apellido'];
 $correo1=$_POST['correo'];
 $contrasena1=$_POST['contrasena'];
 if ($nombre1!=''&&$apellido1!=''&&$correo1!=''&&$contrasena1!='') {
  
 mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO 'usuarios' ('id','nombre','apellido','correo','contrasena') VALUES ('','Hola','Adios','algo@algo.com','santoysena')")or die("Error en la introducción");
 

 }else{
  echo "<script>alert('No pueden haber campos vacíos')</script>";
 }


}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Ya se que al validar el form no introduce los campos requeridos pero lo he hecho de esta forma para poder apreciar mejor el error.

Aquí el otro archivo:

```html
<?php  
$link=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","pass")or die ("No se puede establecer contacto con la base de datos: ".mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($link,"mvo")or die("Error: No es posible conectarse a la base de datos: ".mysql_error());
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $consulta ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");


echo "<table border='2'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Nombre</th>";
echo "<th>Apellido</th>";
echo "<th>Correo</th>";
echo "<th>Contraseña</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))
{
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $columna['nombre'] . "</td><td>" . $columna['apellido'] . "</td><td>" . $columna['correo'] . "</td><td>" . $columna['contrasena'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 echo "<br>";
}

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";





//mysqli_close( $link );
?>
```

Comment: Es este die: `mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO 'usuarios' ('id','nombre','apellido','correo','contrasena') VALUES ('','Hola','Adios','algo@algo.com','santoysena')")or die("Error en la introducción");` . Poniendo mysql_error() no sale nada y en los demás die() sin problema alguno.

Comment: por que en el id le tienes `''`

Comment: Como dice @JackNavaRow creo que el motivo es que el campo 'id' está en blanco, y por norma-nomenclatura ese campo tiene que ser único y not null, confirma si es eso o no, un saludo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente el fallo está en tu `VALUE ('ID')`, no le estas pasando ningún valor alguno. Posiblemente es *único* y *auto incrementada* en tu *Base de Datos* al insertar un registro nuevo. Prueba eliminándole de tu sentencia y a ver si funciona o pásale un valor valido, según como tengas creado tus tablas.

También te he dejado un posible ejemplo de la *[conexión](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)*.

**Veamos un posible ejemplo:**

*conexion.php*

```
//Conexión.
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "mvo");

//comprobar la conexión.
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

*Formulario*

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

//Reseteo
$nombre1 = $apellido1 = $correo1 = $contrasena1 = '';

if (isset($_POST['registrar'])) {
    //Obtener datos.
    $nombre1=$_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido1=$_POST['apellido'];
    $correo1=$_POST['correo'];
    $contrasena1=$_POST['contrasena'];

    //Verdadero inputs.
    if ($nombre1 && $apellido1 && $correo1 && $contrasena1) {
        //Sentencia.
        $query = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`nombre`,`apellido`,`correo`,`contrasena`) VALUES ('$nombre1','$apellido1','$correo1','$contrasena1')");
        //Comprobar sentencia.
        if (!$query) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
        } else {
            echo "$nombre1, los datos se insertaron";
        }       

    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('No pueden haber campos vacíos')</script>";
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <label>Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" />
    <br>
    <label>Apellido:</label>
    <input type="text" name="apellido" />
    <br>
    <label>Correo:</label>
    <input type="email" name="correo" />
    <br>
    <label>Contraseña:</label>
    <input type="password" name="contrasena" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="registrar" value="registrar" />
</form>
```

> **Nota:** te aconsejo por seguridad utilizar sentencias [mysqli prepare](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [PDO.](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) También te aconsejo leer bien
>   [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Gracias, tu ayuda ha sido muy útil. Ya he marcado tu respuesta cómo útil y te he dado un +1.

Comment: @Roger un placer verte ayuda. Suerte con tu proyecto. un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias! :-)